# Django dont create a new instance of a many-to-many field if its field already exists in db, instead increment another field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following classes in my Models.py:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    prod_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Product(models.Model):
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, related_name='products')
```

Currently, if I go under a existing product from django admin and add a new size to an existing product with an existing prod_size value (i.e. prod_size = 8.5 with product_id = 4 in the intermediate table) a new Size object (with its new size_id and product_id = 4 in the intermediate table) and prod_size = 8.5 with quantity = 1 in the Size table are created. I would instead like to increment the quantity field of the existing Size object in the db, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the save method like this:

```
django.db.models import F

class Size(models.Model):
    prod_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size_exists = Size.objects.filter(
             prod_size=self.prod_size, product_id=self.product_id
        ).exists()
        if size_exists:
           Size.objects.filter(
               prod_size=self.prod_size, product_id=self.product_id
           ).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
        else:
           super(Size, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I can't filter in Size by product_id since product_id is only in the intermediate table. Should I be creating my intermediate table using 'through=' to be able to access this data? Thanks

Comment: Have you tested the solution ?

Comment: yup, this is what I get after I enter the prod_size in admin panel:  
 File "\models.py", line 17, in save
    prod_size=self.prod_size, product_id=self.product_id
AttributeError: 'Size' object has no attribute 'product_id'